Build counter C MACRO
I would like to know if, through the C preprocessor, it was possible to have a macro that automatically increments every time the code is compiled.
As if it were a counter of the times the code is compiled. I would need to identify which build a binary file it belongs to.
For example, I would like to use it in a printf at the beginning of the code, so that when I start the program I know which build it belongs to.
Until now I have done it manually, defining a macro by hand and incrementing it manually as if it were a version number, but it is annoying and a source of errors as it is easy to forget to increment it manually before launching the compilation.
Is there a way to do this automatically?

Programmers tend to forget that they are programmers. It's not hard to write a script which increments a number in a source text file then run that script before compilation. All programming IDEs have support for stuff like that. Some even have support for keeping track of a build number (keeping track of the number of compilations is useless I believe, count the number of builds).

There is no way to automatically increase a build counter within the limits of the C language, but the __DATE__ and __TIME__ macros can be used to get a unique string for each build.


if, through the C preprocessor, it was possible to have a macro that automatically increments every time the code is compiled

No.

Is there a way to do this automatically?

No.

I would like to use it in a printf at the beginning of the code, so that when I start the program I know which build it belongs to

If you are using CI/CD systems, typically theres a variable, like gitlab CI_JOB_ID or jenkins BUILD_NUMBER. Locally, I would just use __DATE__ or get the git describe.

Until now I have done it manually, defining a macro by hand and incrementing it manually as if it were a version number,

So write a program to that for you. Typically, such a program is written in the build system environment, in CMake or Bazel or Makefile script used to compile your program.

When using eclipse I have written special program which parses one of the h files and increases one of the definitions. It is run from the "prebuild step" in the build system.

I believe Delphi had IDE support for this without any scripts as early as in the mid 1990s.
